# Fizzbuzz in Python

Tags: python, beginner, unit-testing, fizzbuzz

I'm new to Python and wondering what can be improved with the following super novice program - in terms of the solution and code style etc.

test_fizzbuzz.py

```
import unittest
import fizzbuzz


class TestFizzbuzzFunctions(unittest.TestCase):

    def test_it_converts_multiples_of_three_to_fizz(self):
        self.assertEqual(fizzbuzz.process_number(6), 'fizz')

    def test_it_converts_multiples_of_five_to_buzz(self):
        self.assertEqual(fizzbuzz.process_number(10), 'buzz')

    def test_it_converts_multiples_of_three_and_five_to_fizzbuzz(self):
        self.assertEqual(fizzbuzz.process_number(15), 'fizzbuzz')

    def test_it_does_not_convert_numbers_that_are_not_multiples_of_three_or_five(self):
        self.assertEqual(fizzbuzz.process_number(11), 11)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    unittest.main()
```

fizzbuzz.py

```
def process_number(number):
    result = ''
    if number % 3 == 0:
        result += 'fizz'
    if number % 5 == 0:
        result += 'buzz'

    return result or number
```

Answer (score 2):

This does not appear to be a true FizzBuzz program.  A FizzBuzz program, according to the tag wiki, iterates through the numbers 1-100 and prints the values according to the rules you have.

One thing you did correctly is this:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
```

Many beginners fail to do this.  Also, you used snake_case, which is Python standard too.

One thing I found slightly difficult to understand is this:

```
return result or number
```

This would not compile in many languages, and it also allows the method to have two return types - a `string` and an `int`.  I would adjust this to use an `if` statement and convert the number to a string:

```
if result != '':
    return result

return str(number)
```

This way, the method always returns a string.

Because this is just FizzBuzz, if you are going to create a second method for handling it at all, I would just print from within the function, then you do not need to worry about return type:

```
def process_number(number):
    result = ''
    if number % 3 == 0:
        result += 'fizz'
    if number % 5 == 0:
        result += 'buzz'

    if result != '':
        print(result)
    else:
        print(number)
```

Comment: Even if it works, using `is` to compare to the empty string seems a dangerous business. PEP 8 actually recommends going with `if not result` to check empty sequences, which include strings. I kind of like the OP's approach though, even if it is a little too clever.

Comment: @Jaime So my `if` should be `if result is not '':`?

Comment: No, it should either be `if result != '':` which doesn't require the empty strings to be the exact same object, just have the same content, or the preferred way to check for an empty string is `if not result:`. Take a look at the Programming recommendations section in [PEP 8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#programming-recommendations).

Comment: I downvoted, suggesting the mix of algorithm and Input/Output is terrible.

Comment: @Caridorc I normally wouldn't do this, but it is a FizzBuzz, and the algorithm is just for determining the output, it is not really a calculation.